# from list of strings into list of floats

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file (data.txt) delimited by tab as follows:

```
name    height  weight
A   15.5    55.7
B   18.9    51.6
C   17.4    67.3
D   11.4    34.5
E   23.4    92.1
```

The program below gives the result as the list of strings.

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    col1 = [line.split()[0] for line in f]
    data1 = col1 [1:]
    print (data1)
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    col2 = [line.split()[1] for line in f]
    data2 = col2 [1:]
    print (data2)
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f: 
    col3 = [line.split()[2] for line in f]
    data3 = col3 [1:]
    print (data3)
```

The results are as follows:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
['15.5', '18.9', '17.4', '11.4', '23.4']
['55.7', '51.6', '67.3', '34.5', '92.1']
```

But, I want to get data2 and data3 as the list of floats.
How can I correct above program?
Any help, please.

Comment: @Nolen yes but data2 = map(float, data2) resulted <map object at 0x02E6EDF0>

Comment: This looks like a tsv file - have you considered using the [CSV module ](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html) and changing the delimiter to tabs? You'll only have to open your file once to access all your columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need of reading the file 3 times here, you can do this by defining a simple function that returns float value of the the item if it is a valid number otherwise returns it as it is.

Now read all the lines one by one using a list comprehension and apply this function to the items of each line. So now you've a list of lists, and it's time to unzip that list of lists using `zip(*)` and assign the return value to `data1`, `data2`, `data3`

```
def ret_float(x):
    try:
        return float(x)
    except ValueError:
        return x

with open('data.txt') as f:
    next(f) #skip the header
    lis = [ map(ret_float,line.split()) for line in f]
    #[['A', 15.5, 55.7], ['B', 18.9, 51.6], ['C', 17.4, 67.3], ['D', 11.4, 34.5], ['E', 23.4, 92.1]]
    #unzip the list
    data1, data2, data3 = zip(*lis)

    #if you want data1,data2,data3 to be lists then use:
    #data1, data2, data3 = [list(x) for x in  zip(*lis)]
...     
>>> data1
('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
>>> data2
(15.5, 18.9, 17.4, 11.4, 23.4)
>>> data3
(55.7, 51.6, 67.3, 34.5, 92.1)
```

**Update** : Fixing your solution

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    col2 = [line.split()[1] for line in f]
    data2 = list(map(float, col2 [1:]))   # apply float to each item using `map`
                                          # as `map` returns a `map` object in py3.x
                                          # you have to pass it to list() 
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f: 
    col3 = [line.split()[2] for line in f]
    data3 = list(map(float, col3 [1:]))
    print (data3)
```

**help** on [`map`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> print(map.__doc__)
map(func, *iterables) --> map object

Make an iterator that computes the function using arguments from
each of the iterables.  Stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted.
```

Comment: is there difference between (15.5, 18.9, 17.4, 11.4, 23.4) and [15.5, 18.9, 17.4, 11.4, 23.4]?

Comment: @monica yes first one is a tuple and second one is a list. Use : `data1, data2, data3 = [list(x) for x in  zip(*lis)]` if you want lists.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary so i want list

Comment: @monica I've added that to my solution.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Does not my question has alternative much simpler solution?

Comment: @monica I am not sure about an easier solution than this, but you can fix code by using : `data2 = list(map(float,col2[1:]))` and `data3 = list(map(float,col3 [1:]))`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary thanks. i preferred to use data2 = list(map(float,col2[1:])) and data3 = list(map(float,col3 [1:])).

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary can you please explain me about map?

Comment: @monica `map` applies a given function(in this case `float`) to each item of an iterable and returns a map object in py3.x, in py2.x it returns a new list.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary thanks a lot. when i use map method, should i open file two times in my case

Comment: @monica Yes, your method will still require you to open the file 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `float()` function. It takes 1 arg, which would be the string/var you want to turn into a float.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `float()` command:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    col2 = [float(line.split()[1]) for line in f]
    data2 = col2[1:]
    print(data2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the strings to `float` as you read them:

```
data1 = col1 [1:]
```

becomes

```
data1 = float(col1 [1:])
```

---

But--and I know you didn't ask this--your approach is a little sideways.  You might want to consider a program structure more like this:

```
data0 = []
data1 = []
data2 = []
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    f.readline()
    for line in f:
        vals = line.split()
        data0.append(vals[0])
        data1.append(vals[1])
        data2.append(vals[2])
print(data0)
print(data1)
print(data2)
```

Hope it helps!

(Disclaimer: works with Python 2.7; not sure about 3.x.)

Comment: @ron.rothmanno, Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ed/Desktop/tt.py", line 5, in <module>
    for line in f[1:]:
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    col1 = [line.split()[0] for line in f]
    data1 = col1 [1:]
    print (data1)
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    col2 = [line.split()[1] for line in f]
    data2 = float(col2 [1:])
    print (data2)
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f: 
    col3 = [line.split()[2] for line in f]
    data3 = float(col3 [1:])
    print (data3)
```

Comment: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ed/Desktop/tt.py", line 7, in <module>
    data2 = float(col2 [1:])
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number